# Array of pointers initialized with array of compound literals

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently reading the book "Understanding an Using C pointers" and I stumbled on the following example:

```
int (*(arr1[])) = {(int[]){0,1,2}, (int[]) {3,4,5}, (int[]){6,7,8}}
```

The author then shows a memory layout for arr1[0][0]...arr1[2][2] and it can be seen that the elements are stored in a contiguous region.

I have two questions regarding this example:

1. I don't understand why the first bracket in the declaration of arr1 is necessary, that is, is there a difference to the following declaration:

```
int *(arr1[]) = ...
```

I read it as: arr1 is declared as an array containing pointers to ints.

2. I really don't understand why the example results in a contiguous block. Because:
   If I initialize an array I write

```
a = {...}
```

and list the elements separated by commas. Now, in the preceding example the elements of arr1 should be pointers (unless my understanding of the declaration is wrong). Hence, I would think that for the first member

```
int *(arr1[])= {(int[]){0,1,2},...
```

an array containing 0,1,2 is created and its address (this corresponds to the cast to int[]) is then returned and used as the value of the first pointer. However, if that were true, then the numbers 0,1,2 would be located in a potentially separate memory segment from the numbers 3,4,5.

Can someone explain this further?

Comment: 1. You are correct, the innermost brackets can be omitted. Matter of style, taste, you name it.

Comment: Please share which book this is so we can add it to some upcoming black list.

Comment: Is it this one? https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Using-Pointers-Techniques-Management/dp/1449344186

Comment: @Lundin Has anything been started for this?  I would think the tag wiki might be a good place to put it.

Comment: @dbush Not as of yet. The book recommendation is already haywire, it has taken many iterations to destroy it into it's current state. When the damn thing was undeleted I made a call for increasing the quality standards and introducing a black list [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379637/584518) but the proposal didn't get much attention.

Comment: I think Codidact might be a better place for it regardless, if we could get enough C gurus to chime in. It was discussed [here](https://software.codidact.com/posts/287107), where one can also read all about my merry adventures with book lists on SO.

Comment: Re: “then the numbers 0,1,2 would be located in a potentially separate memory”: Sometimes things do not live up to their potential. “Potential” means some **may** happen, not that it **does** happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the parenthesis in the declaration `int (*(arr1[]))` are required.  Using `int *arr1[]` would be equivalent and more readable.

As for the compound literals having consecutive addresses, there's no requirement for this to be the case.  While it would make sense for compound literals (and named variables) declared in the same scope to have addresses in the same general range, the compiler is free to arrange them however it pleases.

When I tried creating the given array and printing the addresses of each element, I got the following:

```
0x7ffdf47f3880
0x7ffdf47f3890
0x7ffdf47f38a0
```

So in this particular case the compound literals have increasing addresses yet are not adjacent to each other.  There are 4 bytes in between each one, and are therefore not contiguous.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - but wrt to the addresses: I meant the addresses of arr1[0][0]....arr1[2][2]. Not the addresses of the three pointers.

Comment: @P.Jo Address of array elements, i.e. `arr1[0][0] ... arr1[0][2]` will always be contiguous, but not individual compound literals.  As noted above, the compound literals are located 16 bytes apart but are each 12 bytes in size so there is a 4 byte gap between them.

Comment: I get it for a truly multidimensional array - but for the above declaration arr[0] is the first int* ptr and this may point to a totally different location than arr[1] - or is this false?

Comment: @P.Jo Yes, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` point to two separate compound literals.  In the above example they happen to be near each other but not immediately adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why the first bracket in the declaration of arr1 is necessary

It isn't, whoever wrote the code was confused and probably shouldn't be writing programming books and thereby pass on their confusion to others.

This would more commonly be written as `int* arr1[]` and no parenthesis is needed. Declarations use the same rules as "operator precedence", meaning that `int* arr1[]` is always equivalent to `int* (arr1[])`. Adding even more parenthesis from there doesn't achieve anything: `int (((*(arr1[]))))` is still the same type...

> I read it as: arr1 is declared as an array containing pointers to ints.

Correct.

> 2. I really don't understand why the example results in a contiguous block

C makes no such guarantee, so I can see why you are confused. Compound literals like any other arrays, are not guaranteed to have contiguous allocation. They may end up adjacent or they may not, depending on compiler and system.

Only true multi-dimensional arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous, but here you only have an array of pointers, each pointer pointing at a separate array allocated where the compiler sees fit.

The 3 individual `int` items in each compound literal are of course guaranteed to be adjacent to each other though.

Overall you seem to know more about C than the author of whatever book you had the bad luck to come across. So I would advise to stop reading the book, name and shame it, post bad reviews about it on the Internet and so on. (We *still* need that anti-book recommendation black list somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks for making this clear! Well, I am not an expert. I think the book is mostly fine but has some confusing lines in that particular section. But if you learn it from the start, these minor issues can cost a lot of time. It is like a typo in an equation in a math book.

Answer (score 0):

For pointing reading C declarations there is a rule about operator precedence that really helped to me.

> go right when you can, go left when you must

To better understanding you can examine followed link. The source suggested from another answer of question in SO (I don't remember exactly):

http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).